# Single-function typeclass naming in Haskell | "er" vs "has"

Tags: haskell, naming-conventions, typeclass, naming

I find it sometimes hard to come up with reasonable single-function typeclass names. If the method name is a regular verb (like get, write, read...), it's easy to do the same thing Gophers do with single-method interfaces - stick an "er" to the back (Getter, Writer, Reader...) an done. But! If the function name is a noun (name, color...) then adding an "er" to the back no longer works. **Namer** and **Colorer** sound too weird because these words are no longer proper English.

One solution could be to add a "has" to the front. One then would get things like HasName, HasColor and also it would work for verbs - HasGet and HasWrite for example. Is this a good approach or not? What are recommended ways to name single-function typeclasses that house noun-ish things?

Comment: I just don't find the need to write lawless, single function, type classes that often.  Perhaps you can avoid writing such classes to begin with and thus avoid the need to name one?

Comment: I second ThomasM.DuBuisson: if your typeclass isn't in some way mathematically meaningful (and thus has a natural name) you should ask yourself whether a typeclass make sense at all. Very often it is more effective to just use a simple record type.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson how would you decouple things and allow the code to be easily extensible without them? Yes, type classes are not interfaces, but they are the closest thing one can get.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys, often, using functions. ;-)  Though I think the recommendation to avoid classes might be a bit premature without a concrete example.  On the other hand, OO programmers coming to haskell should *avoid the heck out of typeclasses* your intuitions are all wrong!!!

Comment: @luqui I think the Show type class could serve as an example here: you could do without it and have separate functions for every printable type, but that's just not convenient. Having Show as a type class exactly defines the expected behavior / property for a type. You know it'is the same for all types that implement it. This makes code easier to read and extend, don't you agree?

Comment: I tend to use the same name for the typeclass as I do for the function. So if the function is `color`, the class would just be `Color`. That's how the built-in `Read` and `Show` typeclasses are, as well. But I agree with above comments, if you find yourself writing a lot of these it might be time to re-think your interface.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys but the `Show` class has a very clear mathematical meaning, and requires instances to fulfill the law `read . show = id`. (If `read` is actually implemented; often, this should be better understood as `〈paste in a new Haskell file and compile〉 . show = id`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Could you please elaborate on what you mean? Are you suggesting that type classes shouldn't be used as a means of abstracting/constraining function input types?

Comment: I'm saying that you should have a clear reason for wanting a type class, some need that a simple record can't cover.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I usually need not to consume the raw record but feed it to some function and get a result. The functions have to be able to accept any type of record that can be processed into the desired result. Geometric shapes are a good example here - they can have things like Area, Volume or Center, but the shapes themselves can be either rectangles, circles, triangles... Having a type class here would allow for a very easy addition of other shapes.

Comment: I would use `Named` and `Colored`.

Comment: @danidiaz How about "sample" - Sampled?

Comment: @PetrasPurlys For something that can be sampled, "Samplable".

Comment: @danidiaz And for something that represents or contains an actual sample?

Comment: @PetrasPurlys `Sampled` in that case, but I'm a bit uneasy about naming a class of types from the way their values are produced.

Comment: @danidiaz I completely agree that types should not be named that way. Single function type classes, on the other hand, represent only some type property, so maybe they could be named like that, especially if the type that is an instance of the Sample typeclass describes or contains a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that having any prefix means a certain thing and having any suffix means a different thing. Additionally, the class prefix/suffix relates to the prefix/suffix on the member function. This convention should be written explicitly somewhere.

For instance,

```
module Lib.Colour.Class

-- The following convention is followed
-- Let class prefixes denote that the member has a certain attribute
-- or has some state internally manipulatable.
--   Has- abstracts record type, accessed with get<ClassRootName>
--   Is-  Things that *are* another type, coereced with as<ClassRootName>
--   Can- Things that are manipulatable in some way, via do<ClassRootName>
-- Let class suffixes denote types who primarily act on other types
--   -er  A thing that does something to another type

class HasColour a where
  getColour :: a -> Colour

class IsColour a where
  asColour :: a -> Colour

class CanColour a where
  doColour :: Colour -> a -> a

class Colourer a where
  colour :: CanColour b => a -> b -> b
```

The thing I like most from this convention is the concept of giving different meaning to prefix and suffix. This consideration made me write `CanColour` instead of `Colourable`, since something that is colorable is thought of as having an internal state that changes.

Regarding the specifics of "color" and "name", note that these nouns are also verbs. You can name people, you can color hair. I don't find adding an -er to either of these at all objectionable for code--especially measured against the gains of a consistent convention. In my example i use the verb form of color for the member function, so i will only ever use "colorer" in class constraints, which seems fine to me.

Now, this convention ultimately will break down at some point, but until it does it should help the user (you) make reasonable guesses on calling conventions when using the library. It should also help guide you when developing new classes.

So this is one suggestion. Among the packages of Hackage, I don't believe there's a clear standard to guide your design. There are some fair criticisms to the premise of this question (found in its comments). However, the intended design *does* come with precedent. The `diagrams` package, for instance, seems to do something exactly like what you are attempting here. It is a well constructed library written by a very well regarded author.

`diagrams` uses prefixes: Is- [IsName](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-core-1.4.1.1/docs/Diagrams-Core-Names.html); Has- [HasOrigin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-core-1.4.1.1/docs/Diagrams-Core-HasOrigin.html). It uses suffixes: -ed, [Traced](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-core-1.4.1.1/docs/Diagrams-Core-Trace.html); -able, [Transformable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-core-1.4.1.1/docs/Diagrams-Core-Transform.html). Okay, it uses too many, perhaps? It seems to me that a little more self consistency could have been gained with, for instance, `HasTrace` as opposed to `Traced`.

So whatever the standard you adopt, since there is no clear consensus of how to do it, you should at least strive for self-consistency of names to concepts and clearly spell out in comments the adopted standard.